# WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 undocumented databases WSO2METRICS_DB and jpadb

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

A standard installation of Identity Server 5.1.0 creates beside the known WSO2CARBON_DB database two other h2 databases: "WSO2METRICS_DB"  and "jpadb".

Unfortunately we couldn't find any documentation on this databases. Could someone please provide us with an pointer to the docs or give us a hint how to answer the following questions:

- Are these two databases required? For what are they used?
- If you configure WSO2 IS against a MySQL database, do I need to create these databases in MySQL as well?
- Do I need to backup these databases?
- In case of an upgrade of IS 5.0.0 to 5.1.0. How do I handle the two databases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are migrating WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 to 5.1.0, you can refer the official documentation [1].

Metrics is a new feature added to Identity Server with 5.1.0 version. It has a separate database and the datasource is defined in repository/conf/datasources/metrics-datasources.xml file. The metrics feature is by default enabled in the config file repository/conf/metrics.xml file. With this feature, you can view JVM metrics by going to Configure -> Metrics -> JVM Metrics feature in the IS management console. All the metrics related data is stored in this new database.

For the metrics database, the database script is located in IS_HOME/dbscripts/metrics directory and there you can find the tables related to this feature which are created in the metrics database.

If you don't wish to use this feature, you may disable it from the metrics.xml file in conf.

The other jpadb is for the workflow feature introduced with IS 5.1.0. You can find documentation in [2]. So in a migration, these should be created separately and you don't need backup as these are new databases.

For your existing database in IS 5.0.0, there are some schema changes for existing tables. You can find DB migration scripts in [1].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release#UpgradingfromaPreviousRelease-Upgradingthedatabase

[2] http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/09/article-wso2-identity-server-5.1.0-workflow-feature-and-use-cases/

Answer (score 1):

This jpabd is used by human task feature to store the task related information. 
Identity server ships BPEL and HumanTask features and jpabd is part of that.

WSO2_METRICS_DB is used for WSO2 Carbon Metrics. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ML100/JVM+Metrics